# Java multithreading is not working right

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using an `Executor` with 4 threads.

```
Executor exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.numOfThreads);
        Runnable requestHandler = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    getImageForURL(spURL, 0);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        };
        exec.execute(requestHandler);
```

In `getImageForURL`, I am printing the name of the thread and the output looks like this. The output does not look right, or is this how it is suppose to look?

```
name=pool-1-thread-1
name=pool-2-thread-1
name=pool-3-thread-1
name=pool-4-thread-1
name=pool-5-thread-1
name=pool-6-thread-1
name=pool-7-thread-1
name=pool-8-thread-1
name=pool-9-thread-1
name=pool-10-thread-1
name=pool-11-thread-1
name=pool-12-thread-1
name=pool-13-thread-1
name=pool-14-thread-1
```

Comment: Before you assume that Java multi-threading is not working, you should assume that perhaps you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new pool every time (by repeatedly calling `newFixedThreadPool`). You probably want to create the pool just once (when you start your program), and submit multiple `requestHandler` to it.

The output should then look something like:

```
name=pool-1-thread-1
name=pool-1-thread-1
name=pool-1-thread-2
name=pool-1-thread-1
name=pool-1-thread-1
name=pool-1-thread-2
```

with the thread number going up to 4 if the pool is fully utilized.

Comment: I created the executor inside loop. Took it out of loop and works as you mentioned, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want your loop to surround *just* the call to `exec.execute(requestHandler)`, and not the entire block of code that you have there, otherwise you'll be creating a new threadpool every time.

If you loop around just the call to `exec.execute(requestHandler)`, then your output should look something like this (the order of the statements may vary):

```
pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-4
pool-1-thread-3
pool-1-thread-2
pool-1-thread-3
pool-1-thread-4
pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-4
pool-1-thread-3
```